# Execute a full bolck of instructions

Tags: java, hibernate

first of all, i don't find a suitable title for this post, so the current one may seems inappropriate.

second, let me explain my need, i'm trying to execute a block of mulltiple lines of code :

```
 updateDataBase();
 instruction1();
 instruction2();
```

in the end of the execution, i want to make sure that instruction1() and instruction2() have fully been successful, otherwise do some kind of rollback to cancel the updateDatabase().

is there a way to manage this issue without using a new method to undo the updateDateBase() method.

Comment: `try-catch` and have the two methods throw an `Exception` if something goes wrong?

Comment: even with a try-catch block, the update statement will be executed anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I was talking about in my comment... this would put the logic within the updateDatabase() method..

```
public void updateDatabase() throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement updateStmt = null;
    String updateString = "some sql code";

    // save point to roll back to... 
    Savepoint savepoint = con.setSavepoint();    

    try {
        // disable auto commit
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        updateStmt = con.prepareStatement(updateString);

        updateStmt.executeUpdate();

        // call instructions
        instruction1();
        instruction2();

        // if we get here then all is good, commit
        con.commit();

    } catch (Exception e ) {
        // if we get here then instruction 1 or 2 failed... rollback
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
                con.rollback(savepoint);
            } catch(SQLException excep) {
                // log error
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (updateStmt != null) {
            updateStmt.close();
        }
        // set connection back to auto-commit
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception catching and then re-throwing so some other part of the code that is responsible after a rollback can handle appropriately.  The next level would be to define a custom InstructionFailedExecption that extends Exception so you can have some granularity in exception handling.

```
private void execute() throws Exception {

  try {

   updateDataBase();
   instruction1();
   instruction2();

  } catch(Exception ex){
    // new rollback 
    rollBack();
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer can be hellpful, except that i need to create a roolback for an already closed transaction, it will be another update that will erase the data, is it what you say ?

Comment: yes.  the rollBack method could revert the changes that took place in updateDatabase().  If you do not want the data committed, you could set the autoCommit flag to false in the updateDatabase() method and make the calls to instruction1 & 2 from there.  If instruction1 & 2 pass, commit.